# Sending mail with PHP Imap

Tags: php

I could retrieve mails from Gmail server on localhost using PHP Imap, but I could not send one. I already try with functions imap_mail() and mail() Could you tell me how? or any thing is required such as mail server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nearly nobody uses or supports sending mail with IMAP. Use SMTP to send mails out.

Comment: could we use SMTP to send mail on localhost without mail server?

Comment: Yes. you usually relay the mails to a real mailserver, e.g. by installing `ssmtp` as sendmail replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ralphworlddesign.com/blog/?p=80) with some helpful comments, about specifying novalidate-cert (although I agree with cweiske).